# Which units are considered "flat-chested"?

Tags: disgaea-5

There are at least 2 game mechanics I know which only apply to "flat-chested" units (the *Flatty Squad* and the *Anti-Flat Chest* evility). Looking around the Internet I found a few examples, interesting anomalies and educated guesses, but no complete list of all classes and unique characters which are considered "flat-chested" in the context of these mechanics.

I am playing the PC version, if it matters.

Comment: I haven't played DIsgaea 5, but the artwork in the past games made it pretty obvious which female units were flat-chested and which were busty. Less obvious at times where which units were female and which ones were male.